# Drywalling the garage

Tags: drywall, garage

I'm a DIYer trying to make the garage look nice with drywall!

I REALLY APPRECIATE ANY GUIDANCE HERE!!

The problems

1. Pipes are running outside the studs
   [image: I have pipes running outside the studs]
   [image: Water line]
   I think there are two options here

A) Do a double wall, i.e create a new layer of framing

B) Redo the plumbing so that it is inside the walls

C) Put drywall behind this plumbing (which won't look as nice)

2. I have a cement curb along the perimeter
   [image: Cement curb]
   I'm not sure how I can install baseboard if my drywall doesn't go all the way down to the floor. I think it would look ugly to leave it like this, I'm wondering if this is a reason I should create a double wall.
3. I don't know how to finish a sloped roof
   [image: Roof is sloped]
   Should I add horizontal framing so that I can install drywall parallel to the floor? Or should I follow along with the slope?

My understanding is that horizontally would be better since I can add recessed lighting and add insulation.

Thanks so much for these tips!!

Comment: proposal A would work, while clearly marking where the pipes are, so you do not drill in them in the future

Comment: You mention insulation.  Water pipes and cold(freezing) temperatures do not mix, so you want them close to heated space(better in heated space, than in outside walls).  Adding insulation to the ceiling, horizontal will give more insulation space, but can insulate slope ceilings also.

Comment: For 3, do you **want** insulation? (Are you heating/cooling?) And can you clarify how important aesthetics are? (Some people would say that a garage should have pipes showing; others want a perfect man-cave.)

Comment: You might want to add a 1" conduit for EV charging, and a couple more conduits for tool circuits, before you go putting up all that drywall.  Drywall makes everything behind it unmaintainable. Houses need utility spaces, even the Amish have utility spaces.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll respond to the points individually

1. I live in California so it rarely gets very cold, the pipes have been working exposed for a long time
\
2. Good point, I can also insulate sloped ceilings
\
3. Aesthetics are quite important, but I'm not super strict because I don't want to do TOO much work
\
4. I do want insulation because I plan to work in that space like an office. I am not sure whether I will install heating/cooling though, that is probably not going to happen

Comment: 5. Adding an EV charger sounds like a good idea, although I would need to run new circuits and my panel is pretty much full right now. 
\
6. Yeah a new layer of framing is a lot of work, but I do think it'll look then nicest. 
\
7. Yeah I could just paint the curb and it could look okay! But it wouldn't feel like a room as much compared to using actual baseboard

Comment: For the first pic you could build a chase at the top of the wall, and retain some floor space.  For the 2nd pic, any chance you could simply relocate the pipe to the inside of the wall?  Otherwise, I guess you'd have to "fur" out the wall some.